# Not displaying Nan values on markers

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I apologize if this is a possible duplicate. Here is my data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'Year': 2015, 'major': None, 'minor': 57.0, 'patch': None},
    {'Year': 2016, 'major': 129.0, 'minor': 107.0, 'patch': 437.0},
    {'Year': 2017, 'major': 109.0, 'minor': 266.0, 'patch': 2622.0},
    {'Year': 2018, 'major': 61.0, 'minor': 3213.0, 'patch': 2989.0},
    {'Year': 2019, 'major': 2906.0, 'minor': 9780.0, 'patch': 16531.0},
    {'Year': 2020, 'major': 421.0, 'minor': 8447.0, 'patch': 9402.0},
    {'Year': 2021, 'major': 1156.0, 'minor': 13102.0, 'patch': 10323.0},
    {'Year': 2022, 'major': 246.0, 'minor': 8770.0, 'patch': 24588.0}
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to plot the count for all the three releases, but for some reason the `nan` keeps showing up, that too only for `major`. Is there a way I could fix this? here is my code:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2['Year'], y=df2['major'], name='Major', mode='lines+markers', marker=dict(color='brown', size=10), line=dict(color='brown', width=1)))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2['Year'], y=df2['minor'], name='Minor', mode='lines+markers', marker=dict(color='orange', size=10), line=dict(color='orange', width=1)))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2['Year'], y=df2['patch'], name='Patch', mode='lines+markers', marker=dict(color='blue', size=10), line=dict(color='blue', width=1)))

for row in df2.itertuples():
    fig.add_annotation(x=row.Year, y=row.major, text=str(row.major), showarrow=False, arrowhead=1, yshift=10)
    fig.add_annotation(x=row.Year, y=row.minor, text=str(row.minor), showarrow=False, arrowhead=1, yshift=20)
    fig.add_annotation(x=row.Year, y=row.patch, text=str(row.patch), showarrow=False, arrowhead=1, yshift=10)



fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_layout(width=1500, height=900,legend_title_text='Type of Change',template='ggplot2', title = 'Evolution of Breaking Changes over all Releases', xaxis_title = 'Year', yaxis_title = 'Number of Breaking Changes')
fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers')

fig.show()
```

[image]
As you can see the annotations in year 2015 being present for major, but not for patch, I am not sure as to why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the original source data.

Comment: Original source data?

Comment: This code refers to other dataframes (i.e. `df2`) without showing exactly how those dataframes were created.

Comment: `df2` is the name of the data I had mentioned in the question beforehand. If there was something else, it would have been dutifully mentioned

Comment: The original dataframe has `major=None` for 2015.  That value cannot be interpreted as a number, so it appears as `NaN`.  What sort of "fix" are you looking for?

Comment: I think if my data reproduced would essentially clarify the doubt. For the year 2015, for major releases I get a nan in my marker and annotations, which I want to get rid of. ( NaN in the original df, I have converted it to dict for reproducibility purposes). I neither want the marker nor the annotations being displayed for `NaN/None` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is happening because plotly doesn't process text for annotations the same way as for traces. Plotly traces are "smarter" in the sense that they often will drop `NaN` values from displaying for many of the chart types.

This is a case where I think creating scatter traces with `mode='lines+markers+text'` and passing the y values as the text would simplify your problem and avoid having to use annotations at all. `go.Scatter` will handle `NaN` by dropping the marker as well as the text.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [
    {'Year': 2015, 'major': None, 'minor': 57.0, 'patch': None},
    {'Year': 2016, 'major': 129.0, 'minor': 107.0, 'patch': 437.0},
    {'Year': 2017, 'major': 109.0, 'minor': 266.0, 'patch': 2622.0},
    {'Year': 2018, 'major': 61.0, 'minor': 3213.0, 'patch': 2989.0},
    {'Year': 2019, 'major': 2906.0, 'minor': 9780.0, 'patch': 16531.0},
    {'Year': 2020, 'major': 421.0, 'minor': 8447.0, 'patch': 9402.0},
    {'Year': 2021, 'major': 1156.0, 'minor': 13102.0, 'patch': 10323.0},
    {'Year': 2022, 'major': 246.0, 'minor': 8770.0, 'patch': 24588.0}
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df2['Year'], y=df2['major'], 
    text=df2['major'], textposition="top center",
    name='Major', mode='lines+markers+text', 
    marker=dict(color='brown', size=10), line=dict(color='brown', width=1)
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df2['Year'], y=df2['minor'], 
    text=df2['minor'], textposition="top center",
    name='Minor', mode='lines+markers+text', 
    marker=dict(color='orange', size=10), line=dict(color='orange', width=1)
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df2['Year'], y=df2['patch'], 
    text=df2['patch'], textposition="top center",
    name='Patch', mode='lines+markers+text', 
    marker=dict(color='blue', size=10), line=dict(color='blue', width=1)
))

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_layout(width=1500, height=900,legend_title_text='Type of Change',template='ggplot2', title = 'Evolution of Breaking Changes over all Releases', xaxis_title = 'Year', yaxis_title = 'Number of Breaking Changes')
fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers+text')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this approach clearly works better, I didn't think of using scatter. Thank you so much for the detailed answer Derek!